# continuous UDP request to the server not work as expected

Tags: java, groovy, udp

Currently I am working on a performance testing tool and I have to develop a UDP request testing plugin for load testing. I tried to send continuous large number of  request to monitor the maximum load that server could handle. **My goal is to make the application not responsive by sending maximum number of requests but i am not getting the expected result**. My testing application is up and running in my local environment. Is it the fault of the implementation or the configurations. Please help.

```
//UDPRequests.groovy
package com.udp.testsubject;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class UDPRequests {
    static void main(String [] args) {

        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        InetAddress address = null;
        byte[] buf = new byte[65507];
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        //following paramters will get from a property file
        String ipAddr = '127.0.0.1';
        int portDst = 4445;
        int numberOfRequests = 1200000;

        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        address = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddr);
        random.nextBytes(buf);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, portDst);

        try {
            printf("[*] Start send requests to %s:%d\n", ipAddr, portDst);
            int count=0;
            while (count < numberOfRequests) {
                count++;
                socket.send(packet);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an MCVE. What is the expected result, what is the result you're getting, what is the server code?

Comment: hi, I have clearly highlighted above the Expected result and what i getting

Comment: Sever is a node server...angular application

Comment: No way we were to know it was an Angular server.. You say "My goal is to make the application not responsive ... but i am not getting the expected result", but that tells us practically nothing.. What do the server logs say, is it actually getting all these requests, what data is it reading, and how is it acting on those requests? That should get you on the right track but I'm not going to bother more than that because I didn't exactly like your response and an exercise in debugging would be good experience for you anyway. Best of luck.